# Scale factors for the Oblate Spheroidal Coordiante system

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I need the scale factors for the Oblate Spheroidal Coordiante system.  Using Wolfram Mathematica Mathematica, where a is any constant and is the elliptical focus point. The code returns the following result:

\begin{array}{l}
 \frac{a \sqrt{\cos (2 \eta )+\cosh (2 \xi )}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{a \sqrt{\cos (2 \eta )+\cosh (2 \xi )}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 a \sin (\eta ) \cosh (\xi ) \\
\end{array}

---

"ξ">0 ,0<"η"<π   ,-π<"φ"≤π

---

But this result is different from what was published in the MathWorld Encyclopedia

Also contradicts what is published at Field Theory Handbook DOI: 10.1007/978-3-642-83243-7

Can anyone comment which is correct and if there might be a bug?

**UPDATE 1**

to @Jiaxin Zhong    Here is the math code returning various parameters including scale factors.

```
 CoordinateTransformData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", {\[FormalA]}}, 3} -> 
  "Cartesian", "Mapping"]

CoordinateTransformData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", 1}, 3} -> 
  "Cartesian", "Mapping"]

toOblatefromSpherical = 
  CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> {{"OblateSpheroidal", 1}, 3},
    "Mapping"];
%[{1, Pi/4, Pi/6}] // Simplify

fromOblatetoSpherical = 
  CoordinateTransformData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", 1}, 3} -> "Cartesian",
    "Mapping"];
param = CoordinateChartData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", {\[FormalA]}}, 
    "Euclidean", 3}, "StandardCoordinateNames"];
param // Column
(*sph=fromOblatetoSpherical@param//Column;*)
sph = 
 fromOblatetoSpherical@param

Thread[% == {x, y, z}] // Simplify // MatrixForm

sph2 = Simplify[sph /. x_String :> ToExpression[x]] // MatrixForm

CoordinateChartData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", {\[FormalA]}}, "Euclidean", 
   3}, "CoordinateRangeAssumptions"]@param

CoordinateChartData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", {a}}, "Euclidean", 3}, 
   "ScaleFactors", param] /. x_String :> ToExpression[x] // Column

CoordinateChartData[{{"OblateSpheroidal", {a}}, "Euclidean", 3}, 
   "Metric", param] /. x_String :> ToExpression[x] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They all can be true because there are kinds of definitions of oblate coordinates.**

**The best way to check the scale factors depends on the definition of oblate coordinates you adopt!**

There exist 3 canonical definitions of **oblate spheroidal coordinates**. Each of them can depict a oblate spheroid as the 3 coordinates (such as $\eta,\xi,\varphi$) **varying in its domain**. You may check here for details: [Oblate spheroidal coordinates@Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates).

Different definitions serve different specific problems.

For example, the following definition is one of my favorite: (called  **Definition $(\eta,\xi,\varphi)$**)

> Let $0\leq\xi<\infty, -1\leq\eta\leq1, 0\leq\varphi<2\pi$.
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x=a\left[(1-\eta^2)(1+\xi^2)\right]^{1/2}\cos\varphi,\\
> y=a\left[(1-\eta^2)(1+\xi^2)\right]^{1/2}\sin\varphi,\\
> z=a\eta\xi.
> \end{cases}
> $$

I don't know how you get your answer on Mathematica, but I am wondering there may be some typos on the scale factors you post.

**You may check the scale factors according to the definition.**

> **Definition.** The scale factors of $(\eta,\xi,\varphi)$ over $(x,y,z)$ are:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> h_\eta=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\eta}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\eta}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\eta}\right)^2},\\
> h_\xi=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\xi}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\xi}\right)^2},\\
> h_\varphi=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\varphi}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\varphi}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\varphi}\right)^2}.
> \end{cases}$$

Therefore, the corresponding scale factors of the example mentioned above are:

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> h_\eta=a\sqrt{\dfrac{\xi^2+\eta^2}{1-\eta^2}},\\
> h_\xi=a\sqrt{\dfrac{\xi^2+\eta^2}{\xi^2+1}},\\
> h_\varphi=a\sqrt{(1-\eta^2)(\xi^2+1)}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: That you Jiaxin . I added a update showing the code returning my definition.